# The $_GET[] variables become null after form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

`$emailgot` and `$codepass` are printed fine before submitting the form.
After submitting `$emailgot` is printed blank.

The action part of the form refers to the same page.

Undefined variables code and email after submitting the form.

Do I need to pass them somehow in form?

Thanks.

URL has email and code fields filled.

```
<body>
    <header style="padding-top: 2em;padding-left: 2em;">

        <h2> Password Reset </h2>
        <div>
            <header id="messagebox" style="padding-left: 3em;">
            <?php
                if($_POST)
                {
                    echo $message;
                }
            ?>
            </header>
        </div>
    </header>   
    <section class="50% row uniform" style="padding-top: 2em;">

        <form action='passreset.php?code='$codepass'&email='$emailgot'' method="post" class="12u 50% row uniform">

            <div class="8u 6u$(3) 12u$(3) -1u">
                <p>Password : </p>
            </div>
            <div class="8u 6u$(2) 12u$(3) -1u">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="8u 6u$(3) 12u$(3) -1u">
                <p>Confirm Password : </p>
            </div>
            <div class="8u 6u$(2) 12u$(3) -1u">
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" required=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="12u$">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input value="Submit" class="special big" type="submit"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you confusing with `$_POST[]` AND `$_GET` .. ? PS: In `$_GET[]` you will have parameters in your url and not the opposite in the `$_POST[]`

Comment: PHP is a scripting language, variable in scope are not kept after a reload of the page, you need to pass the values you want to transmit in session or in form.

Comment: How do i pass them in forms?

Comment: You're not echoing with PHP... you're just using a literal $emailgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action='passreset.php?code=<?= $codepass ?>&email=<?= $emailgot ?>' method="post" class="12u 50% row uniform">
```

If you don't open a code block, you are just using a literal `$codepass` and `$emailgot` instead of the values of those in PHP.

`<?= ... ?>` is the short open tag for `<?php echo ... ?>`

Update: You also have no use for single quotes.  You were ending the attribute **action** at `passreset.php?code=` because of your usage of the single quote.

Comment: okay thanx..And how do i use them in the script again?

Comment: after using the post method suggested by you...the URL still passes this

Comment: http://localhost/gyanfinal/passreset.php?code=

Comment: did you remove the single quote after `code=`?  look at my bottom paragraph.

Comment: This wrked <form action="passreset.php?code=<?= $codepass ?>&email=<?= $emailgot ?>" method="post" class="12u 50% row uniform">